# How to select drop down value - Vb.net Webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, browser

I want to select a dropdown value with vb.net webbrowser

```
<OPTION value=1>One</OPTION> 
<OPTION value=2>Two</OPTION>
```

The values 1 & 2 are without the quotes

If the value is within quotes such as `value = "1"`

Then I can use the code

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ID").SetAttribute("Value", "1")
```

But it does not work for the above.

Thanks in advance.

Actually it does not matter if there is a quote or not. I created test code and it seems to be working.

```
For Each Frame As HtmlWindow In currentWindow.Frames
  Dim btnElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = 
                 Frame.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Select")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In btnElementCollection
      Dim controlName As String = curElement.GetAttribute("id").ToString
      If controlName = TextBox2.Text Then
        curElement.SetAttribute("Value", TextBox3.Text)
      End If
    Next
Next

                                                                                     TextBox2 is the id TextBox3 is the value
```

Sorry, not sure why it didn't work the first time and thanks for everyones time.

Comment: You should include the value="1" in quotes, so it will work. Otherwise (though I am not sure), try to use SetAttribute("Value", 1) without quotes.

Comment: Are you sure the ID of your element is named ID ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the attribute name to uppercase.

```
<OPTION VALUE=1>One</OPTION> 
<OPTION VALUE=2>Two</OPTION>
```

Note "value" is now "VALUE"

Answer (score 0):

You should set id of the target element.
This should be

```
GetElementById("ID")
```

this

```
GetElementById("element id ")
```

View your page source to get the correct id.